# How to create a custom loop?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I made a custom loop that delays 300ms on it's each iteration. But in this loop, the line `ul.syle.height = i + 'px';` is throwing a error that `TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined at main.js`

But the variable `ul` is working fine above at the line `var ul_scrollHeight = ul.scrollHeight;`.
Then why it is not working inside 'setTimeout'?  **Here `getNextSibling` is another function in my code.**

```js
function fun1() {
    var ul = getNextSibling(this);
    var ul_scrollHeight = ul.scrollHeight;

    
    var i = 1;

    function customLoop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            ul.syle.height = i + 'px'; // Not Working

            if (i <= ul_scrollHeight) {
                customLoop();
            }
        }, 300)
    }

    customLoop();

}
```

Comment: Please also show the relevant html

Comment: is it `ul.syle.height` or `ul.style.height` ? You may make typo in `style` i guess.

Comment: On a side note, `customLoop` seems to be infinite, since neither `i` nor `ul_scrollHeight` ever change.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just have a typo on that line:

```
ul.syle.height = i + 'px';
```

Because `ul.syle` is missing a `t`, so that returns `undefined`, which did not have a property `height`.